# Problems installing scikit-image in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencv, scikit-image

When I try to install scikit-image with pip2 there is show error. I have tried to find this problem solution.

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-image
Storing debug log for failure in /home/nshakib/.pip/pip.log

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might have missing dependencies. I don't think Ubuntu 14.04 comes out of the box with any of the SciPy stack.

To answer your question try,

`sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python-numpy python-pil python-scipy`

Then

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cython
```

Finally

```
sudo apt-get install python-skimage
```

If that still doesn't work, you could try using the Anaconda Distribution for Python 2.7 from Continuum Analytics.
It comes with many of the major packages built-in and has a great package manager that manages dependencies.

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#anaconda-install

The conda package would be installed with `conda install scikit-image`

Comment: Thank you I got my solution :)